# Decode and visualize Protobuf messages over TCP

Tags: protocol-buffers, wireshark

I wrote a socket interface C++ code, between two processes with Protobuf over TCP protocol. The interface works fine, I can decode and send messages over the interface. However I also want to visualize the messages between two processes.

Wireshark is a good tool for listening socket messages. I can store the pcap with tcpdump and open it on wireshark. However it seems I could not make a visual from pcap.

I added protofile folder for wireshark:

[image]

Added a Lua file inside plugins folder:

```
do
local protobuf_dissector = Dissector.get("protobuf")

-- Create protobuf dissector based on UDP or TCP.
-- The UDP dissector will take the whole tvb as a message.
-- The TCP dissector will parse tvb as format:
--         [4bytes length][a message][4bytes length][a message]...
-- @param name  The name of the new dissector.
-- @param desc  The description of the new dissector.
-- @param for_udp  Register the new dissector to UDP table.(Enable 'Decode as')
-- @param for_tcp  Register the new dissector to TCP table.(Enable 'Decode as')
-- @param msgtype  Message type. This must be the root message defined in your .proto file.
local function create_protobuf_dissector(name, desc, for_udp, for_tcp, msgtype)
    local proto = Proto(name, desc)
    local f_length = ProtoField.uint32(name .. ".length", "Length", base.DEC)
    proto.fields = { f_length }

    proto.dissector = function(tvb, pinfo, tree)
        local subtree = tree:add(proto, tvb())
        if for_udp and pinfo.port_type == 3 then -- UDP
            if msgtype ~= nil then
                pinfo.private["pb_msg_type"] = "message," .. msgtype
            end
            pcall(Dissector.call, protobuf_dissector, tvb, pinfo, subtree)
        elseif for_tcp and pinfo.port_type == 2 then -- TCP
            local offset = 0
            local remaining_len = tvb:len()
            while remaining_len > 0 do
                if remaining_len < 4 then -- head not enough
                    pinfo.desegment_offset = offset
                    pinfo.desegment_len = DESEGMENT_ONE_MORE_SEGMENT
                    return -1
                end

                local data_len = tvb(offset, 4):uint()

                if remaining_len - 4 < data_len then -- data not enough
                    pinfo.desegment_offset = offset
                    pinfo.desegment_len = data_len - (remaining_len - 4)
                    return -1
                end
                subtree:add(f_length, tvb(offset, 4))

                if msgtype ~= nil then
                    pinfo.private["pb_msg_type"] = "message," .. msgtype
                end
                pcall(Dissector.call, protobuf_dissector, 
                       tvb(offset + 4, data_len):tvb(), pinfo, subtree)

                offset = offset + 4 + data_len
                remaining_len = remaining_len - 4 - data_len
            end
        end
        pinfo.columns.protocol:set(name)
    end

    if for_udp then DissectorTable.get("udp.port"):add(0, proto) end
    if for_tcp then DissectorTable.get("tcp.port"):add(0, proto) end
    return proto
end

-- default pure protobuf udp and tcp dissector without message type
create_protobuf_dissector("protobuf_udp", "Protobuf UDP")
create_protobuf_dissector("protobuf_tcp", "Protobuf TCP")
-- add more protobuf dissectors with message types
create_protobuf_dissector("Oamc", "OamcPacketProto",
                          false, true, "OamcPacketProto")
```

end

And when I try to decode as below:

[image]

TCP messages appears but no protobuf payload appears in the wireshark as in this Tutorial [Wireshark tutorial](https://wiki.wireshark.org/Protobuf#write-your-own-protobuf-udp-or-tcp-dissectors)? [image]

Am I missing something? My proto file looks something like below:

```
message OamcPacketProto {
  oneof packet {
    .....
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue might be caused by:

1. You may not capture all the TCP packages of the communication.
2. Your package may not format in [length (4bytes) + protobuf payload].
3. The length of your package might be little endian format. You should modify following code

```lua
  local data_len = tvb(offset, 4):uint()
  ...
  subtree:add(f_length, tvb(offset, 4))
```

to

```lua
  local data_len = tvb(offset, 4):le_uint()
  ...
  subtree:add_le(f_length, tvb(offset, 4))
```

Answer (score 0):

In this file, the first 4 bytes are considered as the total size of the packet
If the first 4 bytes in your package are the size of the package, then the next thing you should pay attention to is the order of your bytes in little endian or little endian, and based on which one, use the le_uint() or uint() functions to calculate the package length.
And if the length of your packet has no header and it is all data, then the length of your packet is equal to local remaining_len = tvb:len()
The image below is an example of a Lua file without headers

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFqD0.png)